# SQL Oracle Like-for-like comparison

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following dataset:

**Table1**
[image]

2021 is my base year, and I want to know which of these products that started 2021 also occurred in 2022. So only if a product has a Contract_start in 2021, I want to pull this same product with contract_start in 2022 as well.

My output should therefore look like this
[image]

I tried below query. This approach fails to include all four instances of product C, instead it only pulls one product C for 2021 and one for 2022. How to fix this query so that all products starting in 2021 are included in the right number of rows, without causing duplication for the 2022 products?

```
with values_2021 as
(       select distinct
        CUSTOMER_NUMBER||PRODUCT as productcust
        
        from table1
        
        where substr(CONTRACT_START,1,4) = '2021'
 )

SELECT distinct
        CUSTOMER_NUMBER,
        TOTAL_DOLLARS,        
        PRODUCT,
        CONTRACT_START,
        CONTRACT_END         
       
  FROM  table1
  join values_2021 on (table1.CUSTOMER_NUMBER||table1.PRODUCT) = values_2021.productcust
  
  where CONTRACT_START >= ('20210101')
```

Comment: `table1.CUSTOMER_NUMBER||table1.PRODUCT` comparisons are risky. and bad for performance. (Ruins index usage.) I.e. don't do it!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how performant this would be with your data, but hopefully it points you in the right direction.

```
SELECT b.*
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT customer_number,
                        product
        FROM   table1
        WHERE  Substr(contract_start, 1, 4) = '2021') a
       inner join table1 b
               ON a.customer_number = b.customer_number
                  AND a.product = b.product
                  AND b.contract_start >= ( '20210101' )
```

Comment: This could not be working. Correct your sintax, please....

Comment: @dr well the code runs and produces the desired result. So i guess it must be magic? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3bd83d/1

Comment: Question is specific - catch 2021 and 2022. Your code will catch 2023 as soon as it happens. Suppose that (with the same sample data) the question was - catch 2019 and 2020. Following the same logic of your where and join conditions your code would catch all from 2019 to 2022. Regards....

Answer (score 0):

One option is to extend what you are doing using common table expressions. Create another CTE for 2022. Then, join both back to the main table. As jarlh mentioned, join both columns instead of using string concatenation. Switching the SUBSTR to LIKE could allow an index to be used if one exists on contract_start.

```
WITH values_2021 AS (
    SELECT customer_number
          ,product
      FROM table1
     WHERE contract_start LIKE '2021%'
     GROUP BY customer_number
             ,product
),values_2022 AS (
    SELECT customer_number
          ,product
      FROM table1
     WHERE contract_start LIKE '2022%'
     GROUP BY customer_number
             ,product
)
SELECT t1.customer_number
      ,t1.total_dollars
      ,t1.product
      ,t1.contract_start
      ,t1.contract_end
  FROM table1 t1
  JOIN values_2021 v2021 ON ( t1.customer_number = v2021.customer_number
   AND t1.product = v2021.product )
  JOIN values_2022 v2022 ON ( t1.customer_number = v2022.customer_number
   AND t1.product = v2022.product );
```

Comment: This returns 10 rows. There should be just 8....

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way is as said in the question - *products that started 2021 also occurred in 2022*. With the data as in the quesstion you can try this:

```sql
Select  *
From    table_1
Where   PRODUCT IN (Select PRODUCT From table_1     Where Substr(CONTRACT_START, 1, 4) = '2021') And  -- products 2021
        PRODUCT IN (Select PRODUCT From table_1     Where Substr(CONTRACT_START, 1, 4) = '2022') And  -- products 2022
        SubStr(CONTRACT_START, 1, 4) IN('2021', '2022')
```

... resulting as

| CUSTOMER | TOTAL_DOLLARS | PRODUCT | CONTRACT_START | CONTRACT_END |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | A | 20210614 | 20220613 |
| 1 | 60 | A | 20220614 | 20230613 |
| 1 | 800 | B | 20211031 | 20221030 |
| 1 | 900 | B | 20221031 | 20231030 |
| 1 | 600 | C | 20210614 | 20220613 |
| 1 | 0 | C | 20210707 | 20220706 |
| 1 | 646 | C | 20220614 | 20220711 |
| 1 | 0 | C | 20220707 | 20230706 |

Regards...